# Rabbitmq + Spring AMQP: resend msg but no ack return

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I use spring amqp to send msg, and add the resend logic if ack=false, with the same rabbitTemplate

```
 @Bean
public RabbitTemplate customRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
   RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
   rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
   rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
   rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {

       RabbitMetaMessage metaMessage = (RabbitMetaMessage) mqMsgUtil.getMetaMsg(cacheKey);
       //1 receive ack
       if (ack) {
       // send success   
           mqMsgUtil.setMsgSuccess(cacheKey);
           SUCESS_SEND = true;
       // send failed
       } else {

           reSendMsg(cacheKey, metaMessage, rabbitTemplate);
       }
   });

  public void reSendMsg(String msgId, RabbitMetaMessage rabbitMetaMessage,RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
     rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(rabbitMetaMessage)
     .....
  }
```

I can "1 receive ack" when I send msg first time, but when in seSendMsg and send msg again with RabbitTemplate, I can not receive ack again. How this happans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a message on the ack callback is not allowed; it causes a deadlock in the client library. You need to do the re-send on a different thread.

In the next release (2.1) we have changed the code to invoke the callback on a different thread to avoid the user code having to do it. See [AMQP-817](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-817) and its linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580507/java-rabbitmq-client-hangs-on-resend-via-thread-of-producer-commit-callback-afte/50585338#50585338).

Comment: thanks.There is another question  do the re-send on a different thread: if re-send success, how to stop the re-send in the main thread? Are there any reference code to  do resend?